# Date picker todate

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am using date picker my question is date when i select today date next 7 days is enabled and , now if i select date before today date the next 7 days is no disabling, date picker counting next 7 days from today date,

```
           var dateFormat = "yy-mm-dd",
                            from = $("#fromdate").datepicker({
                        defaultDate: "+1w",
                        changeMonth: false,
                        maxDate: "7d",
                        minDate: new Date(2010, 1 - 1, 1),
                        altField: "#actualDate",
                        numberOfMonths: 1,
                        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                    }).on("change", function () {
                        to.datepicker("option", "minDate", getDate(this));
                    }),
                            to = $("#todate").datepicker({
                        //                                defaultDate: "+1w",
                        changeMonth: false,
                        numberOfMonths: 1,
                        maxDate: "7d",
                        dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd'
                    }).on("change", function () {
                        from.datepicker("option", "maxDate", getDate(this));
                    });

                    function getDate(element) {
                        var date;
                        try {
                            date = $.datepicker.parseDate(dateFormat, element.value);
                        } catch (error) {
                            date = null;
                        }
                        return date;
                    }
```

Comment: if i select every date only 7 days will be enabled

Comment: try  minDate: 0,
   maxDate: "7d",

Comment: Thanks for your response,  minDate disabled all dates before today date i want if i select every date in "from date" in "to date" only 7 days will be enabled.